# systemd-resolved is not using the DNS servers provided by DHCP - using mysterious IPv6 addresses instead

Tags: networking, networkmanager, dns, dhcp

At home, my router provides DHCP (192.168.1.1), and another server hosts a local DNS cache (192.168.1.157). I do not have a DHCPv6 server.

The router is correctly set up, and the only nameserver it is sending over DHCP is 192.168.1.157. Other (Windows, Android) clients on the same network are able to correctly configure their DNS via DHCP.

However, on my Pop_OS! 20.04 system, there are two extra nameservers that `systemd-resolved` seems to have acquired from somewhere else:

```
~ resolvectl
(snip)
Link 3 (wlp0s20f3)
      Current Scopes: DNS                      
DefaultRoute setting: yes                      
       LLMNR setting: yes                      
MulticastDNS setting: no                       
  DNSOverTLS setting: no                       
      DNSSEC setting: no                       
    DNSSEC supported: no                       
  Current DNS Server: fe80::f6f5:e8ff:fe61:8e90
         DNS Servers: fe80::f6f5:e8ff:fe61:8e90
                      2605:a601:558e:d500::1   
                      192.168.1.157
```

And, it seems to be using the IPv6 nameserver to resolve DNS queries, which means they are not hitting my LAN's DNS server. Randomly, a reboot will result in the correct DNS server being used (192.168.1.157), but this is only 1/3 of the time.

Where did these extra DNS servers come from? How can I resolve the issue?

---

Note: There are other questions about missing DNS servers on Ask Ubuntu, but I believe this question is unique, as my DNS server is not "missing" - it is just accompanied by 2 unwanted IPv6 DNS servers.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a DHCPv6 service?  If it's using the IPv6 nameserver, that means you have full IPv6 networking working on your LAN.

Comment: @BrianTurek yep, I tried acquiring a DHCPv6 lease using dhclient with no success. But it's come to my attention that IPv6 has built in mechanisms for DNS discovery that don't require DHCP, so that could explain it...

Comment: Hi, I'm having a similar issue on Ubuntu 20.04.3... in my case is `fe80::1` instead of `192.168.1.32` (which would be my pi-hole)